# jQuery Mobile Back Button After Form Submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I'm having an interesting issue in jQuery Mobile (JQM).

You should know beforehand that I have a single-page template setup (separate pages) setting the following global configuration options, largely with the goal of turning off ajax and the jQM hash navigation system.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = "false";
$.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = "100";   
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";    
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = "false";
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = "false";
$.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = true;
});
```

**The Problem**

I have a search result page, which obviously displays search results. Within the page is another form that allows the user to refine their search. Sometimes the user will decide that that they don't liked the refined results, and they'll want to click the back button to display their original results set. The problem is, on the JQM site, when the back button is clicked/tapped for this purpose, instead of being brought back to the original search results, the user is taken to the site's index page.

The interesting thing is, the page (minus the JQM-specific scripts/css) is identical to the static html version. That version behaves like it should.

**Question:**

Am I missing a global configuration option that would be helpful here? Is there anything else specific to JQM that could be causing this?

**The Markup:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<title>Search Results</title> 
<!-- JQM CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<!-- Custom Theme CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/cayce.css" />
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
<!-- Custom Jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Mobile-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='js/jquery.mobile.1.2.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
</head>  
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="searchresults">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" data-icon="back" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
<a href="WebCatPageServer.exe?Landing" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-right">Menu</a>
<div class="header-sub">
<div class="logo">
<a href="WebCatPageServer.exe?Landing">
<img src="themes/images/logo.png" width="100" height="49" alt="Company Logo">
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content">
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">
<p>We found a total of <b>SPI_SearchHitCount</b> products containing<p>
<p><b>"SPI_SearchStrDisp"</b></p>
<!--Results SPI_SearchStart thru SPI_SearchEnd-->
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-content-theme="d" style="margin-top:15px;">
<h3>Refine/New Search</h3>
<form name="RefineSearchForm" id="RefineSearchForm" method="post"  action="WebCatPageServer.exe?DO_SEARCH">
<input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Search">
<input name="SearchType" type="hidden" value="AND">
<input name="FullSearch" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchFull">
<input name="PrevSearchText" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchPSearch">
<input name="Start" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="New" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchNew">
<input name="Refine" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchRefine">
<input name="SearchMF" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchSearchMF">
<input type="search" name="Search Term" id="refinesearch" value=""  />
<div class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a">
<!-- SPI_HTML_RefineResults_Btn -->
<input type="submit" name="refinesearch" data-theme="c" value="Refine Search"/>
<!-- SPI_HTML_RefineResults_Btn --></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><input type="submit" data-theme="c" name="newsearch" onClick="javascript:document.RefineSearchForm.Refine.value='NO';document.RefineSearchForm.PrevSearchText.value='';document.RefineSearchForm.New.value='YES';" value="New Search"></div>
</div><!-- /grid-a -->
</p>
</form>
</div>
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a">
<!-- SPI_HTML_PrevResults_Link -->
                    <form name="PrevSearchForm" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe?DO_SEARCH" class="noprint">
                        <input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Search">
                        <input name="SearchType" type="hidden" value="AND">
                        <input name="FullSearch" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchFull">
                        <input name="PrevSearchText" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchPSearch">
                        <input name="Start" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchPrevStart">
                        <input name="New" type="hidden" value="NO">
                        <input name="Refine" type="hidden" value="NO">
                        <input name="SearchMF" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchSearchMF">
                        <input name="SearchText" type="hidden" value="">
                        <input name="ResultsPerPage" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchResultsPerPage">
                        <input type="submit" data-icon="arrow-l" value="Previous" />
                    </form>
<!-- SPI_HTML_PrevResults_Link -->
</div>
<div class="ui-block-b">
<!-- SPI_HTML_NextResults_Link -->
                    <form name="NextSearchForm" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe?DO_SEARCH" class="noprint">
                        <input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Search">
                        <input name="SearchType" type="hidden" value="AND">
                        <input name="FullSearch" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchFull">
                        <input name="PrevSearchText" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchPSearch">
                        <input name="Start" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchNextStart">
                        <input name="New" type="hidden" value="NO">
                        <input name="Refine" type="hidden" value="NO">
                        <input name="SearchMF" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchSearchMF">
                        <input name="SearchText" type="hidden" value="">
                        <input name="ResultsPerPage" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchResultsPerPage">
                        <input type="submit" data-icon="arrow-r" value="Next"/>
                    </form>
<!-- SPI_HTML_NextResults_Link -->
</div>
</fieldset>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Results -->
<form name="AddItem" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe">
<input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Add_Item">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-dividertheme="d" data-split-icon="plus" data-split-theme="d">
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_LevelEntry -->
<li data-role="list-divider" class="listdivider">SPI_Level3Entry</li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_LevelEntry -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry1 -->
<li class="prod">
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Thumbnail -->
<a href="SPI_ProdFullLink"><!--<img src="SPI_ProdThumbnail" width="75" height="75" alt="SPI_ProdEntryID"/>-->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Thumbnail -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_LinkItemNum -->
<h3>SPI_ProdEntryID</h3>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_LinkItemNum -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry_Others -->
<p class="space"><b>Part #</b>: SPI_ProdEntryOther</p>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry_Others -->
<p class="description"><b>Description</b>: SPI_ProdEntryDesc</p>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowViewPriceAvail -->
<p class="space"><b>Qty Avail</b>: SPI_ProdQtyAvail</p>
<p class="space"><b>Unit Price</b>: <span class="price">SPI_ProdEntryPrice</span></p>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowViewPriceAvail -->
<input type="number" class="nolink" name="SPI_CartOrdQtyFieldName" value="" tabindex="SPI_CartOrdQtyTabIndex" />
</a>
<input name="SPI_CartProductIDFieldName" type="hidden" value="SPI_ProductID" class="noprint"/>
<input name="SPI_CartMfgProdIDFieldName" type="hidden" value="SPI_MfgProdID" class="noprint"/>
<input name="SPI_CartProductDescFieldName" type="hidden" value="SPI_ProductDesc" class="noprint"/>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:if (document.AddItem.SPI_CartOrdQtyFieldName.value==0){document.AddItem.SPI_CartOrdQtyFieldName.value='1'};document.AddItem.submit();">Add</a>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
</li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry1 -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry2 -->
<li class="prod">
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Thumbnail -->
<a href="SPI_ProdFullLink"><!--<img src="SPI_ProdThumbnail" width="75" height="75" alt="SPI_ProdEntryID"/>-->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Thumbnail -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_LinkItemNum -->
<h3>SPI_ProdEntryID</h3>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_LinkItemNum -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry_Others -->
<p class="space"><b>Part #</b>: SPI_ProdEntryOther</p>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry_Others -->
<p class="description"><b>Description</b>: SPI_ProdEntryDesc</p>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowViewPriceAvail -->
<p class="space"><b>Qty Avail</b>: SPI_ProdQtyAvail</p>
<p class="space"><b>Unit Price</b>: <span class="price">SPI_ProdEntryPrice</span></p>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowViewPriceAvail -->
<input type="number" class="nolink" name="SPI_CartOrdQtyFieldName" value="" tabindex="SPI_CartOrdQtyTabIndex" />
</a>
<input name="SPI_CartProductIDFieldName" type="hidden" value="SPI_ProductID" class="noprint"/>
<input name="SPI_CartMfgProdIDFieldName" type="hidden" value="SPI_MfgProdID" class="noprint"/>
<input name="SPI_CartProductDescFieldName" type="hidden" value="SPI_ProductDesc" class="noprint"/>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:if (document.AddItem.SPI_CartOrdQtyFieldName.value==0){document.AddItem.SPI_CartOrdQtyFieldName.value='1'};document.AddItem.submit();">Add</a>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
</li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Product_Entry2 -->
</ul>
</form>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Results -->
<br>
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-block-a">
<!-- SPI_HTML_PrevResults_Link -->
                    <form name="PrevSearchForm" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe?DO_SEARCH" class="noprint">
                        <input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Search">
                        <input name="SearchType" type="hidden" value="AND">
                        <input name="FullSearch" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchFull">
                        <input name="PrevSearchText" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchPSearch">
                        <input name="Start" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchPrevStart">
                        <input name="New" type="hidden" value="NO">
                        <input name="Refine" type="hidden" value="NO">
                        <input name="SearchMF" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchSearchMF">
                        <input name="SearchText" type="hidden" value="">
                        <input name="ResultsPerPage" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchResultsPerPage">
                        <input type="submit" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="c" value="Previous" />
                    </form>
<!-- SPI_HTML_PrevResults_Link -->
</div>
<div class="ui-block-b">
<!-- SPI_HTML_NextResults_Link -->
                    <form name="NextSearchForm" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe?DO_SEARCH" class="noprint">
                        <input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Search">
                        <input name="SearchType" type="hidden" value="AND">
                        <input name="FullSearch" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchFull">
                        <input name="PrevSearchText" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchPSearch">
                        <input name="Start" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchNextStart">
                        <input name="New" type="hidden" value="NO">
                        <input name="Refine" type="hidden" value="NO">
                        <input name="SearchMF" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchSearchMF">
                        <input name="SearchText" type="hidden" value="">
                        <input name="ResultsPerPage" type="hidden" value="SPI_SearchResultsPerPage">
                        <input type="submit" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="c" value="Next"/>
                    </form>
<!-- SPI_HTML_NextResults_Link -->
</div>
</fieldset>
</div><!-- /content -->
<div data-role="footer">
</div><!-- /footer -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#searchresults').on('pageshow', function () {
    $('a input.nolink').each(function() {
        var default_value = this.value;
        $(this).focus(function() {
            if(this.value == default_value) {
                this.value = '';
            }
            $('a input.nolink').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            );
        }
        );
    }
    );
    $('body').append('<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-transition="pop" >'+
            '<p>Please enter keyword(s) in the search input field.</p>'+
            '</div>');
    $( "#popupBasic" ).popup();
    var search_cmds = $('input[name="newsearch"][type="submit"]').attr('onclick');
    $('input[name="newsearch"][type="submit"]').attr('onclick','');
    $('input[name="refinesearch"], input[name="newsearch"][type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#refinesearch').val()=='') {
            //$( "#popupBasic" ).trigger('create');
            $( "#popupBasic" ).popup( "open" );
            setTimeout(function() {
                $( "#popupBasic" ).popup( "close" );
            }
            ,1500);
            return false;
        }
        if ($(this).attr('name')=='newsearch') {
            /*document.RefineSearchForm.Refine.value='NO';
            document.RefineSearchForm.PrevSearchText.value='';
            document.RefineSearchForm.New.value='YES';*/
            eval(search_cmds);
        }
    }
    )
}
);
</script>
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Thanks**
I appreciate your time very much, guys!

**Update**
This is now resolved. I had syntax errors in my JQM global configuration options. This should look like the following:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 100;     
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
$.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">
```

Try the jqm built-in function that works like this

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">back</a>
```

For further info and details check official documentation here

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Let me know if it was useful

Comment: Thanks. I did try that originally. It didn't make a difference in this instance. Also, it's my understanding that the data-rel="back" built-in function is only applicable with ajax enabled, anyway.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see ajax was disabled... I think it would be useful for performance and to use all features to have it activated, many problems would be easier to manage, but I can imagine you have your reasons not to activate it